# Camera lag when when using cv2.VideoCapture(4) with tkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

Disclaimer: I am only marginally experienced in cv2 and Tkinter , so pardon me if this question is silly.

What am I trying to do? 
I am trying to read input from 2 cameras at the same time and display the resulting frames using a Tkinter GUI in real-time.

What is the issue I am facing? 
There is a significant lag in the dual video streams when displayed using tkinter.

What have I tried? 
I have checked if this issue persists when displaying a single video frame and the issue does not persist.

code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def show_frame_left():
    _, frame = cap_left.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain_left.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain_left.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain_left.after(10, show_frame_left) #previously 10 

def show_frame_right():
    _, frame = cap_right.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain_right.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain_right.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain_right.after(5, show_frame_right) #previously 10 

#Set up GUI
window = tk.Tk()  #Makes main window
window.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
window.wm_title("Cleron Vsoft")

#Graphics window
image_frame_left = tk.Frame(window, width=600, height=500)
image_frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

#Capture video frames
lmain_left = tk.Label(image_frame_left)
lmain_left.grid(row=0, column=0)
cap_left = cv2.VideoCapture(4) #1(side cam) ,  3(top cam),4(int top cam) works

#Slider window (slider controls stage position)
sliderFrame_left = tk.Frame(window, width=600, height=100)
sliderFrame_left.grid(row = 600, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

show_frame_left()  #Display 2

#Graphics window
image_frame_right = tk.Frame(window, width=600, height=500)
image_frame_right.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)

#Capture video frames
lmain_right = tk.Label(image_frame_right)
lmain_right.grid(row=0, column=0)
cap_right = cv2.VideoCapture(3) #1(side cam) ,  3(top cam),4(int top cam) works

#Slider window (slider controls stage position)
sliderFrame_right = tk.Frame(window, width=600, height=100)
sliderFrame_right.grid(row = 600, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

show_frame_right()  #Display 2

window.mainloop()  #Starts GUI
```

error :
youtube link: https://youtu.be/mRVVyHfkXBc

How do I display my dual video feed without lag?

Comment: A good start:   this will consume more processing power, but should still be viable, like watching two tv shows at the same time. So smaller images, a better processor... possibly `multiprocessing` or `threading` on the code side.

Comment: tkinter's `after` will cause the frame reading to block the entire gui loop. you **must** use threads or VideoCapture's `waitAny`. the issue has nothing to do with processing power. nothing at all.